# Downloading pandas output as saved files instead of links

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add an image to each episode for a podcast scrape. The RSS feed is a great help, but it seems the unique link for each episode can't be used as it's not an actual link as there's no .jpg etc.:

```
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CriminalShow/~4/sr-KhpKmTO0"
```

As such, any requests to pull the src= don't work for obvious reasons. I have managed to pull each relevant episode's image from the other part of their website using this code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['image'])
df['image'] = df['image'].apply(pd.Series)['large'].replace({'"': '\'','""': '\'','"""': '\'' }, regex=True)
df.to_csv("RSS-alt-img.csv",encoding='utf-8',index='false')
```

How would I make pandas actually download these files to a local folder so I can reference the local files in the rest of the code? All the stuff I can find online is about scraping links etc.

I know one issue will be the output won't have any  parts to each output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported regex so that you can save the file name in a organized manner.

Try the following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import re


resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['image'])
df['image'] = df['image'].apply(pd.Series)['large'].replace({'"': '\'','""': '\'','"""': '\'' }, regex=True)
Regex_Pattern = r"([^\/]+$)"

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    match = re.findall(Regex_Pattern, row['image'])
    myfilename = ''.join(match)
    print(row['image'])
    print(myfilename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['image'], myfilename)
```

Comment: @Ian-Fogleman Thanks! I'm getting this error though:
  File "./RSS-alt-img2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request

Comment: Are you using python 2.x?

Comment: I'm positive I installed 3.something the other day but it's telling me I'm using 2.7

Comment: You might need to install the module with pip: pip install requests, or use import urllib if your python 2.X, if you have multiple installs of python I would uninstall 2.X as its a bit confusing managing modules between two versions.

Comment: that was it, I installed 3.7 and replaced urllib.request references with just urllib as requests has been integrated within python itself in 3+ it seems. Thanks for your help